# How to tell who was the author of removed line?

Tags: git

Lets say I have a particular commit in git, which contains some line removals. How to easily check who authored removed lines?

What I do now is:

```
git blame THE_FILE.TXT THE_REVISION^
```

which annotates all lines as they were before the change. This requires manual scrolling and finding lines that I know are removed in next commit.

Is there any better way, to only annotate changed lines (displayed by  `git show` or `git diff`)?

This is not about finding when was specific line removed (as in the other question), but doing the opposite - finding when was the removed line introduced. Still no answer to that.

An example:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/d6d211db37e75de2ddc3a4f979038c40df7cc79c#diff-b67911656ef5d18c4ae36cb6741b7965L4

The problem is to easily identify the commit which introduced the line "EXTRAVERSION = -rc4", which is now removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict `git-blame` to a given line range using its `-L` option. As the line number may be different in `THE_REVISION^`, I suggest you use `-L :<regex>` instead of a range of line numbers.